# Why are there no co-op jobs on Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I've been looking at the job boards for a while now, and I have yet to see any listings for co-op positions. Are companies simply not interested in paying the amount to be listed if the employment is for the short-term only? Or are the companies that know of Stack Overflow simply uninterested in hiring co-ops? Has there ever even been a co-op listed? I think a lot of companies could get some fairly talented people as interns, so why do you suppose this is?

Answer (score 3):

I would image that there are few internship/co-op positions listed because Fog Creek charges for the job placements. While the fee is justifiable for a company looking for a full-time, permanent savior, it makes much less economic sense for a short-term person.

Comment: Plus if you're doing a co-op position, you're usually seeking college kids, and it's easier to work directly with the colleges.  The colleges don't charge anything.

Comment: This is true. I went to Northeastern U in Boston which has Co-Op coordinators in each department for matching students with companies.

Answer (score 3):

Co-Ops and Internships are generally handled via other avenues (such as directly working with local schools that are ready to supply businesses with fresh student talent). Advertising this sort of position does not make financial sense overall. If there was going to be any advertising, I would expect it to be a lot more local because it is not very common for people to go for internships that are not local, unless that opportunity came with things like free room and board and other big perks.

Answer (score 2):

Having gone through a co-op program at my university, I can say that this is not how co-ops work.  The school itself sets up various job openings at companies, and then the students apply for them through the school.  The only sort of advertising that would make sense is a general "hey, we're open to hiring co-ops, please contact us" sort of announcement by the company, but it's generally easier for the company's HR/Personnel department to contact the various Co-op Coordinators directly (normally, just the schools nearby).

Comment: Being on co-op currently and being in a program that requires co-ops, I can say that the school does not have to set up job openings at companies, because that's not how my school does it. We are allowed to intern anywhere that will take us whose job description works with our curriculum. Arrangements are then made afterwards when it comes time for student evaluations.

Comment: Cool, I haven't heard of that system, but it sounds like it would work. (What country, BTW? I went to school in Canada.)

Answer (score 0):

Our intern program deals directly with the intern programs at the universities we recruit from.