# Add minimal formatting capabilities to Careers summary block

Tags: feature-request, jobs, markdown

I would like to have some sort of formatting capabilities for the Careers *"Summary"*.

If not full blown WMD, then maybe just like we have with comments + CRLF + bullet points.

Comment: @Glorfindel nope. Careers Stack Overflow. Missed the tag at first.

Comment: Did that even exist seven years ago?

Comment: @Glorfindel of course, it started shortly after Stack Overflow itself. [This is first question with the tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/why-are-there-no-co-op-jobs-on-careers), posted in June 2009. :-)

Comment: That was the paid version, way back when.  Oh, the memories...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added in one of the many redesigns Careers went over the years since this was posted:

> [image]